# Map a 32 bit float to a 32 bit integer

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Is there a way to map floats to ints or unsigned ints so that with the exception of NaN, order is preserved?

So if a and b are floats, and F is the mapping function,

a < b implies F(a) < F(b)
and 
a == b implies F(a) == F(b)

Comment: Yes, I think I've seen such a mapping before - it was quite clever - I just wish I could remember *where* I saw it...

Comment: May I ask your use case for such a mapping?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hm, just out of the `DawsonCompare` routine in Game Programming Gems 6, it's a normal bit-cast followed by a sign flip (since negative floats order opposite then negative integers). I'll borrow that idea.

You have:

```
// utility
template <typename R, typename T>
R& bit_cast(T& pX)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<R&>(pX);
}

// int32_t defined in <boost/cstdint.hpp>. 
boost::int32_t float_to_int_bits(float pX)
{
    boost::int32_t x = bit_cast<boost::int32_t>(pX);

    if (x < 0)
        x = 0x80000000 - x;

    return x;
}
```

If you can guarantee your `int` is 32 bits, you can just use that.

---

Fun fact: The book goes on to use this (note, not with the exact code I present, since I stripped out the float-to-int part) to compare floating point values with tolerance:

```
bool DawsonCompare(float pX, float pY, int pDiff)
{
    int x = float_to_int_bits(pX);
    int y = float_to_int_bits(pY);

    int diff = x - y;
    return abs(diff) < pDiff;
}
```

This compares floats as true if their integer representations are within a certain range. (He uses 1000 as a good default.) A branch-less version called the `LomontCompare` is presented with the same idea, but you have to buy the book for that. :)

Comment: +1 here is a great related link: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Answer (score 2):

Just to eliminate the potentially-slow `if` from the other answers…

```
int32_t float_to_int( float f ) {
    int32_t i = reinterpret_cast< int32_t& >( f );
    uint32_t sgn = static_cast< uint32_t >( i ) >> 31;

    return i ^ -sgn & numeric_limits<int32_t>::max();
}
```

Note that unlike the other solution, this incorrectly handles `0` and `-0`. As floats they compare equal, but after mapping to integers they become `0` and `-1`, respectively. As a single hiccup in the number line, I don't think it would be easy to handle that case without a branch instruction.

Of course, this assumes two's complement arithmetic, `float` being IEEE 754 single, same endianness and same address space for floats and ints, etc.

Comment: Ah, now I see, `INT_MIN` => `INT_MIN - INT_MIN`. Thanks.